# std::condition_variable wait_until timeout или наступление события

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Не ругайте сильно, это, практически первая попытка написать что-то многопоточное. Сделал некий класс Logger

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <csignal>
#include <memory>
#include <list>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::unitbuf;

std::atomic_bool g_stop{false};

class Logger
{
public:
    ~Logger() {};
    static Logger* get_logger()
    {
        static Logger logger;
        return &logger;
    }
    void log(const std::string& _msg)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(m_msg_mutex);
        m_messages.push_back(_msg);
        cout << unitbuf << "--- added " << _msg << " size: " << m_messages.size() << endl;
    }
    void log_job(std::atomic_bool& stop)
    {
        while (!stop)
        {
            log("Logger OK");
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(m_cv_mutex);
            {
                m_cv.wait_for(ul, std::chrono::seconds(m_interval), [&]() { return (m_messages.size() >= m_limit); });
                flush();
            }
        }
        flush();
        cout << unitbuf << "Logger exited" << endl;
    }
protected:
    std::list<std::string> m_messages;
    const unsigned int m_limit {12};
    const unsigned int m_interval {3};
    std::condition_variable m_cv;
    std::mutex m_cv_mutex;
    std::mutex m_msg_mutex;
    Logger() {};
    Logger(const Logger& _obj); // no copies
    const Logger& operator=(const Logger& _obj); // no assignment
    void flush()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(m_msg_mutex);
        for (const std::string& s: m_messages) cout << unitbuf << s << endl;
        m_messages.clear();
    }
};


class Device
{
public:
    Device(){}
    void job(std::atomic_bool& stop)
    {
        Logger* logger {Logger::get_logger()};
        int cnt {0};
        while (!stop)
        {
            std::string s = std::string("msg") + std::to_string(cnt++);
            logger->log(s);
            usleep(200000);
        }
    }
};

void sig_handler(int _sig)
{
    switch (_sig)
    {
    case SIGTERM:
        g_stop = true;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "No, no, no, David Blaine, no street magic!" << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    signal(SIGTERM, sig_handler);

    Logger* logger = Logger::get_logger();

    std::thread thr([&]() {
        logger->log_job(g_stop);
    });

    Device d;
    std::thread jtht(&Device::job, d, std::ref(g_stop));

    jtht.join();

    thr.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Хочется задать условие, при котором цикл будет повторяться при тайм-ауте или превышении размера `m_msgs`. Подскажите, как такое сделать. Заранее благодарен.

UPD: компилятор - не старше c++14 и нет возможности обновить.

Comment: *"проблема здесь"* - описание проблемы в студию

Comment: Я сделал так: `m_cv.wait_until(ul, chrono::seconds(3), [&]() { return m_msgs.size() > limit; });` но почему-то условие не срабатывает. Как должно выглядеть условие?

Comment: *"но почему-то условие не срабатывает"* - а такое заявление следует подтвержlать, приводя [mcve]

Comment: Вместо ссылки на сторонний ресурс следовало бы отредактировать вопрос.

Comment: Исправил. Не знал, виноват.

Answer (score 2):

1. У `m_cv` никогда не вызывается метод `notify_one`, соответственно проверка условия может произойти только случайно. Его следует вызывать, когда изменяется условие, например в конце `log`.
2. Почему-то сделано два мьютекса, `m_msg_mutex` и `m_cv_mutex` соответственно при доступе к условию возникает состояние гонки, что является неопределенным поведением.
3. После вызова `wait_for` вызывается `flush`, который пытается рекурсивно захватить мьютекст, что является неопределенным поведением.
4. Использование в обработчике сигнала функций, не являющихся async-signal-safe (в т.ч. любых методов `cout`), является неопределенным поведением.

Comment: Весьма благодарен за советы, т.к. это мой первый опыт в многопоточности. По пункту 1: вы имели в виду метод `log`? П.2: Какой-то мьютекс надо убрать/изменить - можно более детально? Мне пока плохо понятно, что не так. П. 4: `cout` здесь только для прмера, в итоговом коде его не будет.

Comment: Да, метод `log`. Убрать можно любой мьютекс - главное, чтобы он один остался и защищал все операции со списком. Когда останется один мьютекс, то при вызове `flush` из цикла внутри `log_job` он будет блокироваться дважды.

Comment: Предположим, я уберу `m_msg_mutex` и внутри метода `log` буду использовать `m_cv_mutex` - такое решение приемлемо?

Comment: Вполне приемлемо. Я бы его назвал messages_mutex, чтобы было понятно, что он защищает.

Comment: Спасибо, ваша помощь бесценна!